# Check if a column is null or not before inserting another record in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to check first if the `EndTime` column in my table is null or not before I can insert another record. If the `Endtime` column is not null than a new record can be inserted else an error must be thrown. I'm not sure how to create the error in SQL.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDowntimeEventStartByDepartmentID]
   (@DepartmentId int,
    @CategoryId int,
    @StartTime datetime,
    @Comment varchar(100) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN TRY
   PRINT N'Starting execution'

   SET @StartTime = COALESCE(@StartTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

   INSERT INTO DowntimeEvent(DepartmentId, CategoryId, StartTime, EndTime, Comment)
   WHERE EndTime = NULL
   OUTPUT
       inserted.EventId, inserted.DepartmentId, 
       inserted.CategoryId, inserted.StartTime,
       inserted.EndTime, inserted.Comment   
   VALUES(@DepartmentId, @CategoryId, @StartTime, NULL, @Comment)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DowntimeEvent](
    [EventId] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](100) NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax instead of `INSERT...VALUES` to be able to use a WHERE clause (with a different condition to the one you tried to use, see below), then check the [number of affected rows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) and [raise an error](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) if it is 0:

```
...

BEGIN TRY
    ...

    INSERT INTO DowntimeEvent
      ...
    SELECT @DepartmentId, @CategoryId, @StartTime, NULL, @Comment
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.DowntimeEvent
      WHERE DepartmentId = @DepartmentId
        AND CategoryId = @CategoryId
        AND EndTime IS NULL
    );

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      RAISERROR ('A NULL row already exists!', 16, 1)
    ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ...
END CATCH;
```

(Of course, you will need to omit *your* WHERE clause as invalid Transact-SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a prevention mechanism at the database level rather than just in your stored procedure, so as to be able to prevent invalid additions from any caller, you may want to consider a trigger.

A `FOR INSERT` trigger like this would check if new rows violate the rule "Do not add rows newer than the existing NULL row" (as well as "Do not add older rows with empty `EndTime`") and roll back the transaction if they do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DowntimeEvent_CheckNew
ON dbo.DowntimeEvent
FOR INSERT, UPDATE

-- do nothing if EndTime is not affected
IF NOT UPDATE(EndTime)
  RETURN
;

-- raise an error if there is an inserted NULL row
-- older than another existing or inserted row
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.DowntimeEvent AS t
  WHERE t.EndTime IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM inserted AS i
      WHERE i.DepartmentId = t.DepartmentId
        AND i.CategoryId   = t.CategoryId
        AND i.StartTime   >= t.StartTime
    )
)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ("An attempt to insert an older NULL row!", 16, 1);
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;

-- raise an error if there is an inserted row newer
-- than the existing NULL row or an inserted NULL row
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM inserted AS i
  WHERE i.EndTime IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.DowntimeEvent AS t
      WHERE t.DepartmentId = i.DepartmentId
        AND t.CategoryId   = i.CategoryId
        AND t.StartTime   >= i.StartTime
    )
)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ("An older NULL row exists!", 16, 1);
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Note that merely issuing `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in a trigger already implies raising a level 16 error like this:

```
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line nnn
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

so, you may not need your own. There would be a difference in the meaning of `Line nnn` between the message above and the one brought by your own `RAISERROR`, however: the line number in the former would refer to the location of the *triggering statement*, whereas the line number in the latter would refer to a position *in your trigger*.